# wbadmin.exe: target image is larger than source HDDs

Tags: windows-server-backup, wbadmin

We're creating a bare metal backup of a server with the following command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\wbadmin.exe start backup -backupTarget:\\192.168.2.212\e\backup_Mo -include:C:,D: -user:<servername>\administrator -password:<password> -allCritical -systemState -vssFull -quiet
```

**Source partitions:**

- Partition C: 101 GB
- Partition D: 142 GB

**Destination files:**

- vhd-file of partition C: 67,5 GB
- vhd-file of partition D: 247,3 GB

**Questions:**

- Why is the vhd-file of partiton C: only 67,5 GB large? pagefile.sys with 32 GB isn't copied, right?
- Why is the vhd-file of partition D: larger than the data on the source HDD?

Comment: How large is Partition D total? If it's fragmented, it has to copy all the "empty" space in between the files as well. Defragment the drive and try again.

Comment: Partirion D: is 399 GB large in total. I have defragmented partiton C and D, but nothing changed. As this is a virtualized server under HyperV, can this be the cause?